# How can you divide the count of unique ids resulting from an inner join of two tables by the count of unique ids in just one of the tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This question seems like it should be simple so I am sure it must have been asked before but I searched and could not find an answer.

I have two tables, one containing a master list of members with demographic data, the other containing a list of members with claims.  They both have a common ID field.  I need to be able to calculate the percentage of unique members in the demographics table with one or more claims against the total number of unique members in the demographics table in a single SQL statement (I am using MariaDB and SQLite).

Essentially, I need to be able to:

```
select count (distinct demo.ID) 
from demo 
inner join claims on demo.ID = claims.ID
```

divided by

```
select count (distinct ID)
from demo
```

but calculate it as a percentage number within a single SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

How about just

```
select count(distinct demo.ID) / (select count (distinct ID) from demo)
from demo
join claims on demo.ID = claims.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the ids in the `claims` table are all valid, you can use:

```
select (select count(distinct id) from claims) / (select count(distinct id) from demo) as ratio
```